# Coding Newton's Laws into C#. Having trouble determining the order of finding what I need

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations

So I'm in high school, and I'm currently in AP Physics 1. We're currently doing Newton's Laws where we draw free-body diagrams and use all the various forces (Tension, friction, weight, that kind of stuff) to find the acceleration or mass of an object or whatever.

I can do these problems without too much issue in class, but right now, I'm trying to use these concepts to build my own physics in C#. By the way, you do not need C# or any programming knowledge to answer my question.

So, basically, I have it that when a kinetic object is touching a static object (ie. when a ball is resting on a table), I create new Forces that store some information about it. The data that is stored is the type of force, the power (in Newtons), whether or not it's constant, and its direction.

Now, I was creating all the forces in the y-axis (in this case it was just Weight and Normals), when I ran into a problem. Creating the weight force was fine. The power is simply the gravity constant (9.8) * the mass of the object. However, it wasn't as simple to find the power of the weight force.

If it was given that the y-axis was in equilibrium, The weight would be equal to the normals and it would be good. If it was given that it was accelerating in the y, I could probably solve for the normal force.

Problem is, I don't know whether the object is accelerating or in equilibrium. So, what do I do here? Is there something I'm missing? I need some conditional logic, so I guess if I knew whether it was going to be in equilibrium or not, I could figure it out, but how do I find this out? Of course, since I am the developer, I have access to all measures such as the mass of the object or slope of the incline and all of that. Maybe I can use something there

Comment: A general purpose physics engine (even for a very limited subset of physics like intro mechanics) is a ***hard*** programming project, requiring deep knowledge of both the problem domain and the variety of data structure and algorithms that have been developed for scientific computing. To even get properly started you'll need some kind of adaptive motion tracking with quality collision detection. Also "power" is a different concept from "force" don't confuse them; sse "magnitude" to describe the size of a quantity (scalar or vector).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have objects and forces.  Motion follows from those.  You don't have to know if advance if the system is in equilibrium or not.   Forget about power; power won't help you.

One resource, although not in C#, is [Vpython](http://vpython.org) (in python) and [Glowscript](http://www.glowscript.org/) (almost the same as vpython, but in a dialect of javascript)  These packages are designed for students to produce physics simulations.  Look at the examples.  Some are complicated; start with the ones called "bounce".